# How to pass a hidden property "draggable" to my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, here-api

I got a working *here map*, now I am trying to add **draggable markers** to the map.

Note: I am using a package/module my company has made. It is a React-friendly package of the here api, in particular mapsjs-core.js & mapsjs-service.js. This allows me to render a `<PlainMap/>` component, where I can pass props like the widht and height for the map to be rendered. As child Components of this `<PlainMap>` I can pass something like a `<Marker>` or a `<Polygon>`.

Now this `<Marker>`has these props

```
position: H.geo.IPoint | H.geo.IPoint[];
icon?: React.ReactElement<any>;
eventListenerMap?: {};
```

I am referencing to this official how-to example from the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/draggable-marker). But I don't have any props or flags I can pass to the `<Marker>` to make it draggable (see line 28 of the link above).

All the Events like tap, pointerenter, pointerleave work fine for me, but the dragging not, because (at least I think so) I have to make the Markers draggable. [event-types](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/events.html).

I would love to pass this draggable to my Marker, but I just don't know how to do this.

Is there a possibility to accomplish this somehow?

Maybe to wrap this ` Component and to add a new property like "draggable" and then just set it to true when using this component? Something like this:

```
<Marker 
   key={index} 
   position={point} 
   eventListenerMap={this.markerEventHandlers}
   draggable={true}
/>
```

Comment: This `<Marker>` component is from your company's private React library? Is there no API document you can refer to? In any case, have you check if there's a `<DraggableMarker>` component you can use, if `<Marker>` has no `draggable` prop, it's possible that the author exported a different Marker component for it.

Comment: There is no document unfortunately. Also there is nothing like a DraggableMarker. From my understanding, they build on top of the mapsjs-core and -service scripts from Here, shouldnt it be easy to just add the logic on top of the `Marker`component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<Marker>` is your company's private/custom React component wrapped around HERE's `Marker` JS class/instance, you will have to add a `draggable` prop to the component (like you have done above) and then update the component's implementation to set the draggable property of HERE's Marker instance like so:`marker.draggable = this.props.draggable`.